# Trying to power up an old pc with a laptop cable?

Tags: windows-98

So i'm trying to start up an old windows 98 model. I was thinking of using the cable from a laptop because it fits into the power supply. Problem is i don't know if its safe, advice?. On the computer it says "AC input: 115V~/230V~,10/5A
60/50HZ

ON the power cable on the other hand, it says 16A 250V

Am i good to go?

Comment: No; You are not good to go.  What type of cable are you trying to use exactly from a laptop?  Provide a url to an image of the cable for us.

Comment: You can use any adapter as long as the amount of Voltage is the same and the amount of Amp is the same or nearly. (the same is better, as with nearly the device will overheat or underpower and thus not last long) In this case, its a clear no.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're simply using the part of the cable from the laptop charger that plugs into your desktop's PSU at one end and into a power plug at the other? I don't think there should be a problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

If it's simply a cable, then all it does is connect the PC to the wall power. If it is a cable and a *power supply*, then it likely will not work, though this is likely not the case you describe as the connector would certainly not fit. A power supply looks like a big box in line with the cable.

Most likely the cable you're talking about looks like this:

[image: 1]

If that's the case, you're good to go. These cables are highly interchangeable and the only thing you need to worry about is the current rating, which in your case seems more than adequate.

Comment: I agree, should be fine.

Comment: @Karan Thanks for fixing the image. I didn't have the reputation required to embed...

Comment: NP, you're good to go now with the upvotes, including mine. :)